# Saving raster as *.tif with tfw worldfile

Tags: qgis, world-file

I am using QGIS 2.16 an I need to save a raster file as *.tif with its world file as *.tfw but I only manage get *.aux.xml world files? Any ideas?

---

Ok, I just found out that when i "export as image" it creates a *.tfw. Minor problem seems to be that i am restricted to the screen resolution.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same "problem". Here the solution:

1. Right-click on the layer (raster) -> export -> save as
2. Activate Create options
3. click on "+"
4. In the column "Name" add "tfw" and in the column "Value" add "yes"

Answer (score 11):

In Raster -> Conversion -> Translate :

select your input and output files, as well as your export option if needed. 
Then, click on the pen icon at the bottom of the window to modify the text lines. Change `gdal_translate` to `gdal_translate -co worldfile=yes` and leave the other options.

When exporting, you should have your world file alongside with your picture. That also works with other file extentions, like jpg.

Answer (score -1):

How could I do it with the versione 3.24? I tried to add the TFW=yes option in the Gtiff format and than made image export but doesn't work. I tried to use gdal_translate with -co TFW=yes option but it dosn't work...

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/234251)