# Plotting the DEM into QGIS 3.10 from the CSV through SAGA

Tags: qgis, dem, saga

I had troubleshot with creating a DEM in QGIS SAGA, using this example:

https://www.geodose.com/2018/09/how-to-create-dem-elevation-profile-qgis.html

When I filled up the box as per below:

[image]

I get an error:

> {'TARGET_OUT_GRID': 'C:/Users/mariuszk/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_9cbcbd1489014d3c90818bbf3b042cd0/processing_7f0bf203da0a4ef4911db2fa9c161165/cc73e078de364beda9f771aadf599ef8/TARGET_OUT_GRID.sdat'}
>
> The following layers were not correctly generated.
>
> - C:/Users/mariuszk/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_9cbcbd1489014d3c90818bbf3b042cd0/processing_7f0bf203da0a4ef4911db2fa9c161165/135b4ceb980d4161bf38535f619b636e/TARGET_OUT_GRID.sdat
> - C:/Users/mariuszk/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_9cbcbd1489014d3c90818bbf3b042cd0/processing_7f0bf203da0a4ef4911db2fa9c161165/cc73e078de364beda9f771aadf599ef8/TARGET_OUT_GRID.sdat
>
> You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.**

Did I miss something?

Or shall I follow this example:

[QGIS 3.10 Creating a DEM from CSV](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343328/qgis-3-10-creating-a-dem-from-csv)

Comment: It says right in the error message that you should "check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information." Did you do that? What did it say?

Comment: Your cell size is 100 degrees. Most probably you are generating an empty grid. Also, you must include the complete log of the algorithm, not only the error.